# TagLib - Segfault when fetching tag

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, taglib

I'm using `TagLib` to get tags from audio files for my application that I'm making using wxWidgets. I have set it up to fetch multiple tags like artist, title, album and all, some files load fine, but some when loaded crashes my application and gives error saying,

```
./build.sh: line 12:  5891 Segmentation fault      ./SampleBrowser
```

I tried running with `GDB`,

```
Thread 1 "SampleBrowser" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Browser::AddSamples (this=0x555555a73e00, file=...) at ../src/Browser.cpp:248
248         std::string Artist = File.tag()->artist().to8Bit(true);
(gdb)
```

Here is the function that is responsible for fetching tags,

```
void Browser::AddSamples(wxString file)
{
    TagLib::FileRef File (file);

    std::string Artist = File.tag()->artist().to8Bit(true);
    std::string Album = File.tag()->album().to8Bit(true);
    std::string Genre = File.tag()->genre().to8Bit(true);
    std::string Title = File.tag()->title().to8Bit(true);
    std::string Comment = File.tag()->comment().to8Bit(true);

    std::string Path = file.ToStdString();
    std::string Filename = file.AfterLast('/').BeforeLast('.').ToStdString();

    int Bitrate = File.audioProperties()->bitrate();
    int Channels = File.audioProperties()->channels();
    int Length = File.audioProperties()->lengthInMilliseconds();
    int LengthSec = File.audioProperties()->lengthInSeconds();
    int SampleRate = File.audioProperties()->sampleRate();

    Data.clear();
    Data.push_back(false);
    Data.push_back(Filename);
    Data.push_back(Artist);
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",Channels));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",Length));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",SampleRate));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",Bitrate));
    Data.push_back(Comment);

    SampleListView->AppendItem(Data);

    db.InsertSample(0, Filename, Artist, Channels, Length,
                    SampleRate, Bitrate, Comment, Path);
}
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: @apoon669, is variable `File` successfully initialized? What is the `file` contains? (the parameter passed to this function).

Comment: @Igor I have this `AddSamples()`, that I call inside 2 other functions, as I have different ways of adding files to my application, via drag and drop and by file browser inside the application, both of which uses this `AddSamples()` to get tags and insert them in the `wxDataViewListCtrl` and `SQLite3` database. `file` here is the parameter passed in the function, which is of `wxString` type. I am able to successfully add files to the application using `AddSamples()`, but say there are 5 files in a directory, 3 will add fine, but other 2 crashes the application and causes segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm calling this function here -https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/cpp-projects/-/blob/master/wxWidgets/SampleBrowser/src/Browser.cpp#L294

and here - https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/cpp-projects/-/blob/master/wxWidgets/SampleBrowser/src/Browser.cpp#L326

Comment: @apoon669, please run your code under debugger and see if the variables are successfully initialized.

Comment: @Igor I added a little check before trying to get tags and properties, I added `if (!File.isNull() && File.tag() && File.audioProperties())` then I'm adding the files, and I have a `else { wxLogDebug("Error, cannot open file."); }`, and for the files that did crash the app now simply logs `Error, cannot open file.`. But why is it not able to open some files? I tried using debugger, I put a break point on `FileRef` and where I get first tag, but I could not find anything. I'm not very good at using a debugger.

Comment: @apoorv669, do you have sufficient permissions to open the file? Do you have permissions for the directory?

Comment: @Igor Yes, all the files are from the same archive that I downloaded from internet, and extracted them in a directory in my `/home` directory. I also tried with other audio files on my system, it happens with some files, even in the same directory, while others open fine.

Comment: @apoorv669, and you have a read/write/execute persmissions on both files AND directrory where the files are? You just need to debug what happens when you drop the file in your program or start dragging. I suspect something simple. Maybe the file is corruptedinside the archive or bad permission? Would be nice to see what function is actually fails and what error is produced.

Comment: @Igor All the files in the directory has same permissions, and I have already tried opening the file that fails to load, in another audio player, and it plays fine. I tried debugging, I don't see anything that stands out, it goes through same steps for all files, and for some files it just crashes when it hits certain files, with no extra information provided, just receives a `SIGSEGV`. I tried converting them with `ffmpeg -i filename new_filename` then it adds those files fine.

Comment: @apoorv669, so you bqasically drag and drop the file from the "Explorer" to your program, right? Are you accessing the file during this operation or you just get the file name? Something there is failing. Maybe your OS is set to have open file handles to be too low?

Comment: @Igor Yes I just drag and drop those files to the application. No I'm not accessing those files during the dag and drop operation, I'm getting the path and then feeding that to `TagLib` to get tags.